# Auto complete Account Name

Tags: trigger, lightning, page-layout, account

I have a requirement where i need to have the Account name at the bottom of the page layout and the Account name value needs to be set by 2 custom fields (First Name and Last Name). So i created a trigger (before insert & before update) but if i leave empty the account name, i get validation error. It is because of the order of execution i suppose. However, is there a way to overcome this ??

Comment: If you wish for the community to assist you with the Apex in question, you should include the code for us to review.

Comment: Due to the order of execution, you may need to explore a custom New Account page that defaults the Account Name in the controller. This will allow you to save the record (getting past system validation) and have a `before trigger` concatenate the custom field values to modify the Account Name.

Comment: Yes, the form won't save if a required field isn't populated before the submit has been posted.  You'll have to override the page with a custom page, I think.  Perhaps you can override the "New Account" button with an Action that includes a default text like "Assigned by System" or something.